# Nested path for swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger-ui

[image: This image is what I have.] I am a beginner in Swagger.
I have made these 2 api docs:

> /user:
>
> /user/{id}:

I want both these paths under

> /user

i.e. /user/{id} should not open differently as shown in image.

I want both get under /user.

Both have get methods. (get all users and get user by id.)

Is there a concept of nested paths? If yes, please guide me to implement it?

P.S: NOT like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30326795/1999190

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwaggerUI: Path shows "Default". How can I change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355613/swaggerui-path-shows-default-how-can-i-change)

Comment: This answer shows the tags. But the paths are still different. On writing getg without user/{id}, it shows duplicate mapping of key

Comment: What renderer do you use? It doesn't look like Swagger UI.

Comment: It is swagger ui only. Trying to make something like this. Its done except the issue I wrote above.   http://petstore.swagger.io/#/

Comment: That screenshot does not look like Swagger-UI